# Is it possible to make adding data using ScyllaDB for python more efficient?

Tags: python, python-3.x, cassandra, nosql, scylla

I try to use ScyllaDB with python however it is quite slow. When I run for instance code shown at the bottom I get:

```
26:23:109998
26:23:112695
```

I care about the best possible performance, unfortunately this time of adding data to the database is definitely too long. Is there any way to speed up this process?

```
        print(datetime.now().strftime("%M:%S:%f"))
        session.execute(
            """
            INSERT INTO log (id, date, message)
            VALUES (now(), %s, %s)
            """,
            (date, message)
        )
        print(datetime.now().strftime("%M:%S:%f"))
```

**UPDATE**

At it was recommended in this topic I decided to use prepared statements and batches in accordance to the official documentation to improve performance of adding data to ScyllaDB. My code at the moment looks in the way shown below however efficiency didn't change significantly. Any other ideas?

```
print("time 0: " + str(datetime.now()))
query = "INSERT INTO message (id, message) VALUES (uuid(), ?)"
prepared = session.prepare(query)

for key in range(100):

    print(key)

    try:

        batch = BatchStatement(consistency_level=ConsistencyLevel.QUORUM)
        for key in range(100):

            batch.add(prepared, ("example message",))

        session.execute(batch)

    except Exception as e:
        print("An error occured : " + str(e))
        pass

print("time 1: " + str(datetime.now()))
```

After running this source code the result looks like this:

```
test 0: 2018-06-19 11:10:13.990691
0
1
...
41
cAn error occured : Error from server: code=1100 [Coordinator node timed out waiting for replica nodes' responses] message="Operation timed out for messages.message - received only 1 responses from 2 CL=QUORUM." info={'write_type': 'BATCH', 'required_responses': 2, 'consistency': 'QUORUM', 'received_responses': 1}
42
...
52                                                                                                                                                                             An error occured : errors={'....0.3': 'Client request timeout. See Session.execute[_async](timeout)'}, last_host=.....0.3
53
An error occured : Error from server: code=1100 [Coordinator node timed out waiting for replica nodes' responses] message="Operation timed out for messages.message - received only 1 responses from 2 CL=QUORUM." info={'write_type': 'BATCH', 'required_responses': 2, 'consistency': 'QUORUM', 'received_responses': 1}
54
...
59
An error occured : Error from server: code=1100 [Coordinator node timed out waiting for replica nodes' responses] message="Operation timed out for messages.message - received only 1 responses from 2 CL=QUORUM." info={'write_type': 'BATCH', 'required_responses': 2, 'consistency': 'QUORUM', 'received_responses': 1}
60
61
62
...
69
70
71
An error occured : errors={'.....0.2': 'Client request timeout. See Session.execute[_async](timeout)'}, last_host=.....0.2
72
An error occured : errors={'....0.1': 'Client request timeout. See Session.execute[_async](timeout)'}, last_host=....0.1
73
74
...
98
99
test 1: 2018-06-19 11:11:03.494957
```

Answer (score 3):

There are several factors that can limit your performance. Starting with the Scylla servers configuration. For example, if you created a cluster with very small, slow network instances. Continuing, with the client side HW and workload on the instance itself, while taking into account number of connections per host, number of threads per connection and other tunables from the driver / connector side. Finally, with the usage of more efficient ways to write information into Scylla using prepared statements.

It will be helpful to know more about the environment you are using and the purpose of the workload to recommend a more specific course of action.

Answer (score 3):

Start with using prepared statements, then execute multiple statements in parallel.

Comment: Taking into consideration your suggestions I decided to use prepared statements and batches however performance is still very low. I added my updated source code to the question. Do you have any suggestions or other ideas?